# How to track ssh connection time, disconnection time and idle time?

Tags: linux, ssh, logs, openssh

How can I track ssh sessions on my server including ssh connection time, disconnection time and idle time?

Here's what I have for connections:

```
cat /var/log/{auth.log,auth.log.1} | grep -i Accepted | sed "s/s*//g" | cut -d " " -f "1 3 4 5 12" | grep -v 127.0.0.1`
```

Currently I have to monitor `tcptrack` in order to track disconnections and idle time.

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked the output of "last", maybe it would be sufficient?

```
server ~ $ last
root     pts/0        10.31.1.162      Fri Dec 11 10:35   still logged in
root     pts/0        10.31.1.162      Thu Dec 10 11:12 - 11:22  (00:09)
root     pts/0        10.31.1.162      Thu Dec 10 09:19 - 11:09  (01:50)
```